# Как структурировать модель с массивами Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Имеется модель для создания моделей времени выполнения услуги мастером

```
class ServiceTimeCreate extends Model
{
    public $service_id;
    public $time;
    public $master_id;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['service_id', 'each', 'rule' => ['required','message' => 'Не удалось определить идентификатор услуги']],
            ['master_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Не удалось определить идентификатор мастера'],
            ['time', 'each', 'rule' => ['required', 'message' => 'Поле с временем не заполнено']],
            ['time', 'each', 'rule' => ['time', 'format' => 'php:H:i', 'message' => 'Неверный формат времени']],
            [['master_id','service_id'], 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\ServiceTime', 'message' => 'Упс, Данная услуга уже существует :)'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Create window.
     *
     * @return ServiceTimeCreate|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */
    public function create()
    {
        var_dump($this);
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return null;
        }

        foreach($this->time as $key=>$serv){
            if(isset($this->time[$key]) and isset($this->service_id[$key])){
                $service_time = new ServiceTime();

                $service_time->service_id = $this->service_id[$key];
                $service_time->master_id = $this->master_id;
                $service_time->time = $this->time[$key];

                $trig = $service_time->save();
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = ServiceTime::findByMaster($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Услуга не найдена :(');
        }
    }
}
```

Отображение модели в интерфейсе

```
<?php foreach ($service as $ser):?><?='
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-3">
            '.Html::activeInput('checkbox', $modelSer, 'service_id[]', ['id'=>'service'.$ser['id'],'class'=>'custom-control-input', 'value' => $ser['id']]).'
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="service'.$ser['id'].'">'.$ser['service_name'].'</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        '.Html::activeInput('text', $modelSer, 'time[]', ['class'=>'form-control form-control-user','placeholder' => 'Время','data-mask'=>'time']).'
    </div>
</div>
'?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Так как услуг может быть много, то к каждой из них нужно свое время. Из чего следует вопрос, как правильно валидировать данную модель и как ее структурировать?

---

На данный момент модель не сохраняется с ошибкой валидации. Также при попытке искусственно воссоздать запись в БД и вывести ее интерфейсе выдается ошибка несоответствия выводимой модели атрибутам (`service_id[]`,`time[]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите исходные коды примеров тут https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform
Там есть примеры с индексами, массивами связанных данных и коллекциями полей. Должно помочь, если выкинуть из примеров код самого виджета и оставить только поля и перебор массива.
Ну и, наверное, нужно объединить пару время-услуга в отдельную сущность.